# Can't identify Django error

Tags: python, django

Seeing the following syntax error, but the urls.py file seems to be correct. What am I missing?

```
SyntaxError at /admin/
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 6)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 6)
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.2
```

Here's the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from events import views

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^events/', include('events.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.root)),
)
```

...

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from events import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='ev_create')
    url(r'^tonight/$', views.tonight, name='ev_tonight'),   
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='ev_create')     # <-- comma missing
    url(r'^tonight/$', views.tonight, name='ev_tonight'),   
)
```

Note that this is on line 5 of your `urls.py` module, but Python could only discover this on line 6 when it encountered something that doesn't fit after your `url(...)` call.